# Get related data of string values in variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have variable `@Projects` which has string data of names like `'Project1;Project2;Project3'`

I have this result by query:

```
SELECT 
    @Projects = (SELECT Project_Title+';'
                 FROM Table20
                 FOR XML PATH(''))
```

I need to get name of **related** projects of projects in the **variable** by taking the `ID` of these projects in `Table 1` to compare it with `Table 2.ID` for getting `Table 2.RelatedProject_ID` to compare it again with `Table 1`.

```
 Table_1                    Table_2

 Project  | ID  |          | ID  |  RelatedProject_ID  | 
 ---------+-----+          +-----+---------------------+
 Project1 | 001 |          | 001 |      015            |  
 Project2 | 002 |          | 002 |      020            | 
 Project3 | 003 |          | 003 |      031            | 
 Project4 | 004 |          | 004 |      032            | 
 Project5 | 005 |          | 005 |      017            |
```

What is the correct way to get name of **related** projects in this case?

Comment: What is `Table20` and how is it related to `Table_1` and `Table_2`?

Comment: @sticky `Table20` isn't related with these tables. My initial data is variable with names of projects separated by commas

Comment: And how would you know which ID a project with a name has if there is not name in any of the tables `Table_1` or `Table_2`?

Comment: @sticky Sorry, I edited `Table1`. Name of project is a field `Project` in `Table1`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for here. If your current query creates a list of all the projects, you already have all of the related projects in your list. Please take some time to review this link, then edit your question. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: adding expected output will help

Comment: will `Table_2` have multiple ID's? or one ID will only have one `Related Project_ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `table_1` to `table20` to get the IDs of projects. Then join `table_2` to get the IDs of the related projects. Finally join `table_1` again to get the names of the related projects.

```
SELECT @RelatedProjects = (SELECT t1b.project + ';'
                                  FROM table20 t20
                                       LEFT JOIN table_1 t1a
                                                 ON t1a.project = t20.project_title
                                       LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
                                                 ON t2.id = t1a.id
                                       LEFT JOIN table_1 t1b
                                                 ON t1b.id = t2.related_project
                           FOR XML PATH(''));
```

(Only works reliable if `table_1.project` is unique. Consider to store the projects in `table20` by their IDs not by their name.)

Answer (score 1):

check this example below:

```
declare @projects varchar(max) = 'Project1;Project2;Project3'

Declare @table_1 table
     (Id int ,
      project varchar(15))

Insert @table_1 values (001, 'project1')
Insert @table_1 values (002, 'project2')
Insert @table_1 values (003, 'project3')
Insert @table_1 values (035, 'project35')
Insert @table_1 values (036, 'project36')
Insert @table_1 values (037, 'project37')

Declare @table_2 table
     (Id int ,
      RelatedProject_ID  int)

Insert @table_2 values (001, 035)
Insert @table_2 values (002, 036)
Insert @table_2 values (003, 037)
Insert @table_2 values (004, 038)
Insert @table_2 values (005, 039)

;with cte as (
    SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS projects
    FROM
    (
    SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@projects,';','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    )t
    CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
 )


 select t1m.project
 from @table_1 t1
 join @table_2 t2 on t2.id=t1.id
 join @table_1 t1m on t1m.id=t2.RelatedProject_ID
 join cte cte on t1.project=cte.projects
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HIUOJ95083)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
Select p.Project, p1.Project as RelatedProject
from Table_1 p 
join Table_2 a on p.Id = a.id
join Table_1 p1 on p1.Id = a.RelatedProject_ID
```